# How can I scrape all articles from a website (including possibly via an RSS reader)?

Tags: web-scraping, rss-reader

Please excuse my ignorance, I'm a regular computer user and have zero knowledge about programming. Anyway, my question is:

Is there a way to obtain (i.e. probably 'scrape' in programming lingo) all articles posted on a particular tech news website? I'd like the output (headline and article and possibly date and author) to ideally come up as plain text so that I can use it in a corpus tool called AntConc as part of my personal and not-for-profit research.

In fact, it would be super convenient if I could do it via my RSS feed reader (feedly or inoreader) for quite a few websites, but that's probably asking for too much, so 'one-by-one' scraping would be fine, too.

Would something like Portia do the trick? Please bear in mind that I know nothing about python, etc. and I need whatever method there is to be very, very simple and straightforward.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's very possible to load data like these from other websites provided they support the feature. In java/android we would just create a simple app that loads the data as Json and then parse it into views like listviews, imageviews etc using adapters,and maybe store in cache.

But here's a great and free course on Udemy you can quickly check it your dream solution

https://www.udemy.com/how-to-make-an-app-build-an-app-business-rss-feed-news-apps/

Or if you have up to $19 for a automatic, high quality RSS reader app without coding at all then you can check out
http://www.shoutem.com/app/rss-feed

Or less quality, simple but free
http://www.appsgeyser.com/create-rss-app/

But it's always best to find a little time and make the app or employ services of a developer

Comment: Thank you Vivee for taking the time to answer! I have an account with Udemy and have skimmed the course, but I'm probably too thick and busy to actually implement it. Would there be any other and quicker way of gathering all that content? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks again, Vivee, I very much appreciate your effort to help! I'll look into the links in greater detail in a minute, but for now it's still beyond my understanding as to how my own RSS reader would enable me to download all articles ever posted on a particular website since the site was launched? Wouldn't simple web scraping be simpler? Just asking :/